# Can I get out of melee range by being Huge but still small?

Tags: dnd-5e, creature-size, reach

When thinking about reach and the space rules in the *Player's Handbook*, I devised the following thought experiment. If I am huge sized, but occupy a space smaller than 5 feet, am I out of range of any potential 5-foot reach enemy?

Here is an illustration:

1. The [PHB clarifies](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/combat#Space) that a creature doesn't occupy the entirety of their space.
2. Let's say I shrink my height sufficiently [using Wild Magic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#WildMagic) (down to ~1.2 feet will do).
3. I use the Rune Knight's Giant's Might to become Large and am now 2.4 feet tall.
4. If I then cast *enlarge* on myself, I am now 4.8 feet tall, but Huge sized (thus occupying a 15 ft x 15 ft space).
5. If I lie prone in the middle of my space, no creature can enter my space to get within 5 feet of me.

Am I, therefore, immune to attacks with a reach of 5 feet?

By extension, if I'm suitably skinny with a 1.2 foot diameter (like a Thri-kreen might be, for example), could I keep my limbs in close and occupy this interior space as a huge creature?

Answer (score 12):

### This fails in step 2 and 5

#### Step 2

You might alter your height, but you stay a *medium sized creature*. Incidently, you don't occupy a cube of 5x5x5 ft, only the ground area of 5x5 ft is measured, and that is the area that **you control**, **you block** and which **you need to fight**. In fact, height is irrelevant.

> #### Creature Size
>
> Each creature takes up a different amount of space. Table: Size Categories shows how much space a creature of a particular size controls in combat.
> Objects sometimes use the same size categories.
>
> [table ignored]
>
> ##### Space
>
> A creature’s space is the area in feet that it effectively controls in combat, not an expression of its physical dimensions. **A typical Medium** creature isn’t 5 feet wide, for example, but it **does control a space that wide**. If a Medium hobgoblin stands in a 5-- foot--wide doorway, other creatures can’t get through unless the hobgoblin lets them.
>
> **A creature’s space also reflects the area it needs to fight effectively.**[...]

#### Step 5

By lying down you don't change the area that is controlled by you, you only gain the *prone* condition. In the prone condition:

> - A prone creature’s only movement option is to crawl, unless it stands up and thereby ends the condition.
> - The creature has disadvantage on attack rolls.
> - An attack roll against the creature has advantage if the attacker is within 5 feet of the creature. Otherwise, the attack roll has disadvantage.

Nothing in the prone condition declares you *lie in the middle of your space*, nothing in it modifies the volume or area you occupy, control, block, or need to fight.

**You still are a huge creature** due to the steps 3 and 4, and thus considered to control/block/require 15x15 feet as the size table dictates. As you control those, anyone adjacent to those squares is within reach for a normal weapon.